# JSP/Java application does not connect to MySQL after deployed on vps

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception

I have created a dynamic web application in jsp/jva and connected to MySQL server which works on localhost database and the database on my vps. Code in connection class:

```
public static Connection con=null;

public static void connection() {

String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://<vps ip>:3306/messages";

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "user", "password");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Error");
}
```

This is the stack trace output when I try to http://vps ip:8080/Messages/CreateMessage. However, this works on http://localhost:8080/Messages/CreateMessage when connected to the db on vps.

```
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at message.jsp.servlet.UpdateMessage.doPost(UpdateMessage.java:293)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have copied the J connector and referred it in the path. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Where is the code surrounding line 293 in UpdateMessage.java?  Are there other exceptions too?

Comment: It's a part of an ongoing research so I'm not allowed to put the whole code out in public. I know it's difficult to understand without seeing the code. At line 293 is connection.connect.con.close();, could this be an issue? This is the only exception. Why isn't is causing a problem on the localhost and only on the vps?

Comment: Ultimately there is another exception.  In the tiny bit of code you show you're ignoring at least one exception - are there other places?  At a guess you're not actually getting a connection and then trying to close it.

Comment: If line 293 says `connection.connect.con.close();` then at least one of those is null. As to why, it is hard for us to know as we do not have all the details about your environment, but finding the route cause of why you have null there is key. As @stdunbar mentioned you have a catch on an Exception without looking into the details of it and there may be more in your code, but as that code is not shown to us, we can't help you to tell you where.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I will look into the pointers you have mentioned. If I'm unable to find out I'll try to anonymous the code and add it here.

Comment: I think even though I mentioned the class path of the J connected, it wasn't picked up the reason the connection object was showing null. But on the localhost it was perfectly fine with the class path. When I copied the connector to /WEB-INF/lib folder and redeployed the war file, it is working fine. Your pointers helped me direct to this solution.

Comment: From the comments above for code on given line,sounds like the when ur trying to close the connection,either it has been already closed or connection has not been correctly established.